# Facebook sharekit 2.0 troubles

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, sharekit

```
- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions {
self.permissions = permissions;

[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];

}
```

Ok, the above code is what I am trying to implement. But this code is giving me two errors. The first one is property permission not found in Facebook and second one is instance authorize authorizeWithFBAppAuth: not found.This is share kit 2.0 so maybe this will not work on it, but I need to stop the Facebook app popping up. P.S. I am a Sharekit noob.

```
     - (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions {

// if we already have a session, git rid of it
[self.session close];
self.session = nil;
[self.tokenCaching clearToken];

self.session = [[[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:_appId
                                     permissions:permissions
                                 urlSchemeSuffix:_urlSchemeSuffix
                              tokenCacheStrategy:self.tokenCaching]
                autorelease];

[self.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    switch (status) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            // call the legacy session delegate
            [self fbDialogLogin:session.accessToken expirationDate:session.expirationDate];
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            { // prefer to keep decls near to their use

                // unpack the error code and reason in order to compute cancel bool
                NSString *errorCode = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:FBErrorLoginFailedOriginalErrorCode];
                NSString *errorReason = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:FBErrorLoginFailedReason];
                BOOL userDidCancel = !errorCode && (!errorReason ||
                                                    [errorReason isEqualToString:FBErrorLoginFailedReasonInlineCancelledValue]);

                // call the legacy session delegate
                [self fbDialogNotLogin:userDidCancel];
            }
            break;
        // presently extension, log-out and invalidation are being implemented in the Facebook class 
        default:
            break; // so we do nothing in response to those state transitions
    }
}];
 }
```

This code above is the original that came with share kit 2.0, if there is a way to stop Facebook app popping up in the above code please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use like below:

```
- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions 
{
self.permissions = permissions;

[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:YES];

}
```

And then check.